# VLC doesn't add subtitles automatically

Tags: 18.04, vlc

Like in the topic, I don't why. The same name in the same folder, nothing helps. I have to add them manually every time I open new video. Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to the `Tools menu`.

Choose `Preferences`.

Click on `Subtitles & OSD`.

On the Subtitles Language tab, next to Preferred subtitles language, write the name of language you want to make default.

Then click `Save`.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: I got it, vlc somehow doesn't add automatically .txt files, .srt extension is needed.